# ElasticSearch not returning results for terms query against string property

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following indexed document:

```
{
    "visitor": {
        "id": <SOME STRING VALUE>
    }
}
```

The mapping for the document is:

```
"visitor": {
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "type": "string"
         }
     }
 }
```

When I run the following query I get results:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
             }
        },
        "filter": {
            "term": { "visitor.id": "123" }
        }
    }
}
```

However this does not:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
             }
        },
        "filter": {
            "term": { "visitor.id": "ABC" }
        }
    }
}
```

I've been thinking this is related to analyzers and have been chasing that down. I've also been wondering if I was wrong to use dot notation to get to the nested visitor property.

**Can anyone tell me why I can't filter for the visitor with the id of "ABC" but can for visitor 123**

Comment: My hunch about analyzers paid off. I found that when setting the visitor.id to "abc" instead of "ABC" I was able get the expected results. I'm looking into what the default string analyzer does when it encounters all caps. However, setting the field to "index": "not_analyzed" in my mapping resolved the issue.

    "visitor": {
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "type": "string"
            "index": "not_analyzed"
         }
     }
 }

Comment: Exactly so. Variants of this question appear tens of times per week. You might find this article of interest: https://www.found.no/foundation/beginner-troubleshooting/ :)

Comment: Thanks for the post, Alex. It was very helpful. The post it linked to: https://www.found.no/foundation/text-analysis-part-1/ was even more helpful.

Comment: The beginner-post is intended to shed light on some unknowns, leaving going in depth of them to the other articles. Glad you liked them! :)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You need to understand how elasticsearch's analyzers work. Analyzers perform a tokenization (split an input into a bunch of tokens, such as on whitespace), and a set of token filters (filter out tokens you don't want, like [stop words](http://www.ranks.nl/resources/stopwords.html), or modify tokens, like the [lowercase token filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html) which converts everything to lower case).

Analysis is performed at two very specific times - during indexing (when you put stuff into elasticsearch) and, depending on your query, during searching (on the string you're searching for).

That said, the default analyzer is the [standard analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) which consists of a [standard tokenizer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-tokenizer.html), [standard token filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-tokenfilter.html) (to clean up tokens from the standard tokenizer), [lowercase token filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html), and [stop words token filter](http://www.ranks.nl/resources/stopwords.html).

To put this to an example, when you save the string "I love Vincent's pie!" into elasticsearch, and you're using the default standard analyzer, you're actually storing "i", "love", "vincent", "s", "pie". Then, when you attempt to search for "Vincent's" with a `term` query (which is **not analyzed**), you will not find anything because "Vincent's" is not one of those tokens! However, if you search for "Vincent's" using a `match` query (which is **analyzed**), you will find "I love Vincent's pie!" because "vincent" and "s" both find matches.

The bottom line, either:

1. Use an analyzed query, such as `match`, when searching natural language strings.
2. Set up the analyzers to match your needs. You could set up set up a custom analyzer that performs a whitespace tokenizer or a letter tokenizer or a pattern tokenizer if you want to get complicated, as well as whatever filters your heart desires. It depends on your use case, but if you're dealing with natural language sentences I don't recommend this because the standard tokenizer was built for natural language searching.
3. You can set the field up to not use an analyzer with the following mapping, which should suit your needs:

   ```
   "visitor": {
       "properties": {
           "id": {
               "type": "string"
               "index": "not_analyzed"
           }
       }
   }
   ```

See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html for further reading.

Comment: I am using elastic search with spring. I need to set "index": "not_analyzed" on spring server rather than on json.

Comment: Links are no longer work.

Comment: Updated link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html

Answer (score 44):

Unless you specify the visitor.id field NOT to be analyzed, every fields are analyzed by default.

It means that **"ABC"** will be indexed as **"abc"** (**lower case**).

You have to use term query or term filter with string in **LOWER CASE**.

I hope the query below will work. ^^

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
             }
        },
        "filter": {
            "term": { "visitor.id": "abc" }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From elasticsearch >= 5.0, `term` only work on property type `keyword`, change your property type from `string` or `text` to `keyword` and your query would work fine.