# elasticsearch with NativeSearchQueryBuilder space and uppercase

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api, elasticsearch-template

I'm using the following code to filter by elastic search java api,it works fine and return result if i use string query ,but If i use text with spaces or uppercase letters it don't return any data

if use

```
    String query={"bool":{"should":[{"term":{"name":"test"}}]}}
```

return data

and if i use

```
  String query={"bool":{"should":[{"term":{"name":"test airportone"}}]}}
```

or

```
  String query={"bool":{"should":[{"term":{"name":"TEST"}}]}}
```

return no data

```
String query={"bool":{"should":[{"term":{"name":"test airport one"}}]}}
BoolQueryBuilder bool = new BoolQueryBuilder();
    bool.must(new WrapperQueryBuilder(query));

SearchQuery searchQuery = new 
             NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withQuery(bool)
            .build();
    Page<Asset> asset =
            elasticsearchTemplate.queryForPage(searchQuery,Asset.class);
        return asset.getContent();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933787/elasticsearch-not-returning-results-for-terms-query-against-string-property

Answer (score 0):

You have two options depending on your use-case.

**First option:** You can use `match` instead of `term` to search for a string if you want to get advantage of ElasticSearch full text search capabilities.

```
{
    "bool": {
        "should": [{
            "match": {
                "name": "test airportone"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

**Second option:** You can also specify that the `name` field is `not analyzed` when mapping your index so ElasticSearch will always store it as it is and always will get the exact match.

```
"mappings": {
    "user": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "string"
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you replay , I'm using         IndexQuery indexQuery = new IndexQueryBuilder().withId(id).withObject(asset).build();
            elasticsearchTemplate.index(indexQuery); How can I index with not_analyzed

Comment: Using
`@Field(type = String, index = not_analyzed)`
`private String name;`
you can import `not_analyzed` from `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.FieldIndex`