# using term in elasticsearch for queries

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-2.0

I have downloaded a sample accounts json database from the elasticsearch website.https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_exploring_your_data.html

I am trying to do some queries on top of it.

For example,

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/bank/account/_count?pretty' -d '{
    "query":{
    "filtered":{
    "filter":{
    "bool":{
    "should":[{"term":{"gender":"M"}},{"term":{"age":35}}]
    }
    }
    }
    }
    }'
```

getting the output for this correctly with the count.

But If I try like the query below, I am not getting the correct result.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/bank/account/_count?pretty' -d '{
"query":{
"filtered":{
"filter":{
"bool":{                        
"should":[{"term":{"gender":"F"}},{"term":{"state":"PA"}}]
}             
}               
}                    
}      
}'
```

I am not getting the correct result.. Is there anything wrong in the query syntax or the way of using it?

Can anyone help here!

Comment: Which is the correct result? What do you expect and what do you get?

Comment: for example with the gender F and state PA there are results. but still im getting the count as 0. but for the first query, im getting it correctly.

Comment: maybe use "pa" and not "PA". but yes, what are you trying to get here ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ElasticSearch not returning results for terms query against string property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933787/elasticsearch-not-returning-results-for-terms-query-against-string-property)

Answer (score 1):

Use lowercase while searching

```
eg- f not F
    pa not PA
```

read this for better understanding [ElasticSearch not returning results for terms query against string property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933787/elasticsearch-not-returning-results-for-terms-query-against-string-property)